# relational link within one table

Tags: sql, database-design

I have Table User, which consists of two columns - id_user and name_user?

| id_user | name_user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vova |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Ivan |
| 4 | Kate |

I need to make relation between two users. If I understood correctly I should make Table relation_ids:

| id_user_1 | id_user_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

Tell me please do I need to double relationships between two users (for example 1-2 and 2-1)? Is there another ways to make relation within one table?

Comment: "Do you need to double relationships".  That depends on what you are modeling and how you intend to use the table.

Comment: I need to send some information from one user to anther in pairs

Comment: The most common case where this comes up is the relationship between two employees, where one supervises the other.  This relationship is not symmetric, so you don't have to enter it twice.  it sounds like your relationship is symmetric, so you will have to fill in the foreign key value in both persons.